# Spring Batch process a one 10gb line into separate items

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have implemented a spring-batch job to process a 10gb file with one item per file and it works great!

But the client just changed it to make it a 10gb file with one single line with all items on it separated by size. Where the size are the first 4 digits of the text which on top of it all is in EBCDIC so I need to translate it into as well.

An example would be:

```
0020aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa0010xxxxxxxxx0021aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay0009xxxxxxxx1aaaaaaa
```

and so on for 10GB worth of text

I have a couple problems with this change...

- I will need a lot of memory now, spring data reads the whole line before processing and possibly splitting it with a `LineMapper`, `RecordSeparatorPolicy` or something
- My logs will fail to display the line error as they did before

Is there any implemetation of `ItemReader<String>` that can handle a situation like this?

Is there a way in Spring batch to read chars instead of lines? Without having to implement my very own `FlatFileItemReader` that reads 4 chars then a length and so on?

P.S: I would rather not pre-process the file into the old format.

Comment: If they are writing this in EBCDIC, I'm assuming this is coming from a mainframe?  If so, is there a copybook for it?

Comment: Why not simply write your own Reader? You can base your code on FlatFileItemReader and instead of reading an item per line, you read first the size and then the appropriate number of chars to get your item. The rest  of the logic should not differ a lot from the FlatFileItemReader. You can even simply overwrite the read-method and set a BufferedReaderFactory from which you can get the used BufferedReader.

Comment: @MichaelMinella I do for the messages, and I already have some part of the system handling it.

Comment: @HansjoergWingeier, That is the solution I am trying now. I found out that there was no out of the box solution to this and started doing exactly that. Thanks for it anyway.