# How to write custom RecordSeparatorPolicy in spring batch?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I use `Spring integration` and `Spring batch` in my project,receive file from ftp with spring integration and and run job with spring batch to handle file,i want to read file with below format:
**4ByteLength**DATA**4ByteLength**DATA**4ByteLength**DATA...
The file has only one line and may be include one million records same as above format, my question is how i can read efficient file with spring batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a custom `RecordSeparatorPolicy` in your case because when the [`isEndOfRecord`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/separator/RecordSeparatorPolicy.html#isEndOfRecord-java.lang.String-) method will be called (to check if the line is the end of a record or not), the entire line would have been already loaded in memory which is obviously what you don't want to do.

What you actually need is a custom item reader that reads items as bytes (according to your requirement) instead of lines.

NB: A similar question here: [Spring Batch process a one 10gb line into separate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318301/spring-batch-process-a-one-10gb-line-into-separate-items)